# FillLimitOrder Error: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined

Tags: 0x

Can anyone help me fix the error of this code:

```
import { BigNumber, providerUtils } from '@0x/utils';
const _0xProtocolFeeMultiplier = 70000;
async function fill() {
  const utils = require("@0x/protocol-utils");
  const order = new utils.LimitOrder({
                  sender: "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
                  maker: "0x55c18a6d97e738d27b29ecd7018e04ef2da8ff0a",
                  taker: "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
                  takerTokenFeeAmount: "0",
                  makerAmount: "2600",
                  takerAmount: "2600",
                  makerToken: "0xad6d458402f60fd3bd25163575031acdce07538d",
                  takerToken: "0x07865c6e87b9f70255377e024ace6630c1eaa37f",
                  salt: "0",
                  verifyingContract: "0xdef1c0ded9bec7f1a1670819833240f027b25eff",
                  feeRecipient: "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
                  expiry: "2014956256",
                  chainId: 3,
                  pool: "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000"
              });
  const signature = await order.getSignatureWithKey(<my private key>,  utils.SignatureType.EIP712);
  var Web3 = require('web3');
  var web3 = new Web3(Web3.givenProvider || 'http://localhost:8545');
  const supportedProvider = providerUtils.standardizeOrThrow(web3.currentProvider)
  const wrappers = require("@0x/contract-wrappers");
  const zeroEx = new wrappers.IZeroExContract("0xdef1c0ded9bec7f1a1670819833240f027b25eff", supportedProvider);
  const amount = new BigNumber(1);
  const gasPrice = await web3.eth.getGasPrice();
  const fee = gasPrice * _0xProtocolFeeMultiplier;
  const tx = 
     zeroEx
        .fillLimitOrder(
            order,
            signature,
            amount
        )
        .awaitTransactionSuccessAsync({ from: "0x884ced9e8eca88fa23370d36f1e4fe4ebc3737af" , value: fee })
        .catch((err) => console.error(err));
}
fill().catch((err) => console.error(err));
```

Error:

```
validationResult: null
TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined
```

Comment: There's no then in your code, can you show the line that causes the error? can you show the full stack trace?

Comment: The full stack is very long, so I put it in this [file](https://www.mediafire.com/file/lp7k7l8ak52amhk/temp/file)

Comment: Tried returning `tx` inside `fill()`?

Comment: One thing I find odd is that in this line `const fee = gasPrice * _0xProtocolFeeMultiplier` gasPrice is a BigNumber so multiplying by _0xProtocolFeeMultiplier a number will not work.